# R order() "returns a permutation"

Tags: r, permutation

In the R documentation, it says

> `order` *returns a permutation* which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order

I understand a permutation to be a reordering of the elements in a list. Google's mathematical definition for "permutation" is "the action of changing the arrangement, especially the linear order, of a set of items."

From the documentation, I expected that calling `order(5:1)` would return `'[1] 1 2 3 4 5'`, a *permutation* of the original vector. I have since learned that it contains a vector of indices such that `(5:1)[order(5:1)]` returns `'[1] 1 2 3 4 5'`.

To me, it seems that order returns a permutation of the indices of a vector, not a permutation of the vector itself.

Does `order` really "return a permutation which rearranges its first argument"? If so, how do you correctly interpret that statement?

Or would it be more correct to say "order returns a permutation of indices which can be used to rearrange its first argument"?

(I realize that this is pedantic, but I'm trying to get better at reading documentation, and it seems that code documentation is by its very nature pedantic.)

Comment: While not technically incorrect as it is, it would be great if you sent better wording to the R developer list. We really need to all participate more in improving the help. It's quite horrendous in some places and makes teaching R quite a bit more difficult.

Comment: Note that "A permutation is a one-to-one mapping of a finite set onto itself". Any deviation from that in my maths undergrad friends' exams scored zero marks. It became a strange mantra for them, such that I still remember it, word perfect, nearly 30 years later. Its not "a reordering of the elements in a list" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permutation can have two meanings:

- It is a function that reorders the elements in a list.
- It is the reordered elements in a list.

The help file here refers to the first definition.

Comment: Thanks. Is there someplace I could have looked to find those two definitions on my own?

Comment: The second definition in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permutation) gives these two options

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking more about the terminology than practical implications, but it's worth noting that the implementation they are providing is more useful and clear. It is valid to call order with multiple vectors, for example when sorting by multiple columns in a dataframe. Returning the index is both more practical than returning a tuple of the combined values, and less ambiguous in mapping back to the original rows in the case of equivalent values.

If you're larger point is that the documentation would be more clear that the return value is index, I agree.

Comment: I agree that the implementation is more useful. My point was concerning the documentation, and I agree that it would be more clear if it stated that the return value is an index, but it seems from the mathematical definition of permutation provided by Spacedman, "a one-to-one mapping of a finite set onto itself," that the documentation is technically correct.

Comment: Agree, and your point is a valid one. I feel like the docs are relying on a relatively obscure version of the definition. I probably should have posted mine as a comment, not an answer. My intent was to document thinking through why it's implemented this way, because it is usually a surprise to the user when they first run order.

Answer (score 0):

`order` returns a vector of indices that would permute input argument into sorted order. `x[order(x)]` will always be identical to `sort(x)`.  The below demonstrates what it means by `returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order`.

```
order(mtcars$qsec)
# [1] 29 31 24 30  7  1 27 22 28  2  5 25 23 12 17 13 16 15 14 10 19 32  3 11 26  4 18 20  8
# [30] 21  6  9

sort(mtcars$qsec)
# [1] 14.50 14.60 15.41 15.50 15.84 16.46 16.70 16.87 16.90 17.02 17.02 17.05 17.30 17.40
# [15] 17.42 17.60 17.82 17.98 18.00 18.30 18.52 18.60 18.61 18.90 18.90 19.44 19.47 19.90
# [29] 20.00 20.01 20.22 22.90

# would be the same as 
mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec),]
```

Comment: Why down vote? What s wrong with this? The above clearly demonstrates the `order` definition.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP did not ask what function to use instead of order, but was mostly puzzled by the wording of the documentation. Your answer provides useful additional information, but id does not address the question.

Comment: Disagree. It is not about what function to use to replace but show what the documentation really means.

Comment: I didn't understand it like that. Anyway, there are further problems: `mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec),]` actually returns a `data.frame` and is not the same as `sort(mtcars$qsec)`. `x[order(x)]` is not always identical as `sort(x)`. That's the case for vectors, but not for `data.frame`s

Comment: The gist is `sorted order`.

Comment: KFB, in your example, order() gives 6th element as "number one" qsec. But in mtcars, the 6th element does not have this "number one" qsec value. Why is that?